# Que significa la ultima línea de mensajes. Al ejecutar composer requiere livewire/livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

saludos amig@s programadores. Estoy incursionando en este tema del livewire y dentro de mi proyecto Laravel ejecuté la linea

```
composer require livewire/livewire
```

Y se ejecutó sin problemas. Alguien me podria indicar que significa lo que se genera al final

```
@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi
```

Agradecida por sus comentarios....

[image: resultados de ejecutar composer require livewire/livewire]

Answer (score 0):

vendor:publish permite la inclusión de recursos asociados al paquete en este caso para livewire no copio nada, pero podrian ser:

```
VIEWS
CSS
JS
CONFIG
LOGS
Entre otros...
```

(copia archivos desde la ubicación original del paquete (carpeta vendor) al proyecto)